# Chrome OS and Tor. Linux wont set up either. Says no space

Tags: linux

I'm not computer expert. Just trying to learn. My problem is Chrome OS and Tor. Linux wont set up either. Says no space. Can anyone splain this to me please? I'm a 54 yr old woman. So I didn't grow up with computers. I know some but don't understand the lingo. I tried looking up answers. I am doing all this to not only learn but because I have had my ID stolen and it has been... h e double hockey sticks..... I want to be a little more in control. Oh... also can I use Linus with USB sticks?